# How to parameterize precision of float on printf format

Tags: c, printf, format-string

I have a C program that output values to stdout from measure. I use `printf` to display them and the format allows me to change the precision

```
 printf("Scan=%d S_0=%.5f S_1=%.5f S_2=%.5f S_3=%.5f", scanId, S0, S1, S2, S3);
```

My issue is that I have a lot of printing like this one and if I want to change the precision quickly I have to get on each one and change it. I was wondering if it was possible to use something like a `#define` to have it on a precise location and it will apply on each `printf` at compilation. I know it is not possible easily without recompile but I'm ok with that. I know something similar as I ask here in python is:

```
f"{s_0:.{prec}f}"
```

Comment: No quick or easy or global-defaulty way, no.  If you want to you can say `int prec = 5; printf("Scan=%d S_0=%.*f S_1=%.*f S_2=%.*f S_3=%.*f", scanId, prec, S0, prec, S1, prec, S2, prec, S3);`, but that may be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Thank you, It looks heavy yes but that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to do a `#define` (as you guessed) like this:

```
#define PFLT "%.5f"

printf("Scan=%d S_0=" PFLT " S_1=" PFLT " S_2=" PFLT " S_3=" PFLT, scanId, S0, S1, S2, S3);
```

Then to change the precision you just need to alter the `#define` and recompile.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `*` symbol in place of the precision, in which case the precision is given as a parameter.  Then you can define a constant to pass to `printf`.

```
#define P_FLOAT 5

printf("Scan=%d S_0=%.*f S_1=%.*f S_2=%.*f S_3=%.*f", 
       scanId, P_FLOAT, S0, P_FLOAT, S1, P_FLOAT, S2, P_FLOAT, S3);
```